# Create EF db instance for every insert?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a worker thread, whose job is to insert Objects that are stored in a Queue into the database.

We are currently using Entity framework to do the inserts.  Now my question is, do I need to make a new Db Instance for every insert? or can I safely re-use the same db instance over and over?

```
private static void MainWorker()
    {            
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IncomingDataQueue.Any())
                {              
                    if (IncomingDataQueue.TryDequeue(out var items))
                    {
                        //Insert into db
                        using (var db = GetNewDbInstance())
                        {
                            if (db != null)
                            {
                                db.DataRaw.AddRange(items);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                //Skip everything and continue to the next loop
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteException("Failed to insert DB Data", ex);
                //Delay here in case we are hitting the db 2 hard.
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //Wait here as we did not have any items in the queue, so wait before checkign again
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
    }
```

Here is my function which gets a new DB Instance:

```
  private static DbEntities GetNewDbInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            var db = new DbEntities();
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            return db;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error in getting db instance" + ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now I have not had any issues to date, however, I worry that this solution will not scale well if we are for example doing 1000s of inserts per minute?

I then also worry that with 1 static db instance that we could get memory leaks or that object will keep growing and not manage it's db connections properly?

What is the correct way to use EF with long term db connections?

Comment: `Now my question is, do I need to make a new Db Instance for every insert?` What happened when you tried to do two inserts with the same instance?

Comment: i think the recommended best practice in EF about keeping long connection is _not to_, but to keep it as short-lived as possible. but if _all_ you're doing with that context is `INSERT`ing, i don't really see any problem to switch to a long-lived connection if you're _actually_ getting any performance problems.

Comment: Or at the very least a _medium_ lived connection (e.g. reuse the same connection for 200 inserts).